# How to apply a whitelist to an input that has a drop down menu

Tags: php, sanitization, whitelist

How can I use sanitisation on drop down menu's?

I know how to sanitise using normal user input something like this:

```
$variable_name = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $_POST['key'] );
```

But how can I produce something like this for a drop down - say a list of fruit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to put the possible choices in an array, iterate over it when generating the form element, and use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to validate it.